# Amazon s3 bucket name

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm working on an Android app which allows users to upload images to Amazon S3. I need to get the "storage" information from server in order to do the upload. However, the server does not return a bucket name filed. Instead, it returns a "host" filed which is "something.s3.amazonaws.com". I assume "something" should be the bucket name. Can someone confirm that for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per AWS documentation (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html):

In a virtual-hosted–style URL, the bucket name is part of the domain name in the URL. For example:

- `http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com`
- `http://bucket.s3-aws-region.amazonaws.com`

Comment: The server also returns a "policy" field. However, I found using the Android SDK provided by Amazon, it only requires access key, access secret and bucket name to upload photos. Do I need to worry about the policy information?

Comment: If you are planning to allow users other than the owner of the bucket to access your s3 resources, you will need to control that (grant permissions to create, read, delete data). One of the options is to use policies. You can find out more about it at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-iam-policies.html.